# Execute named query using HibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am developing a small application using Struts, Spring and hibernate3. But now I find trouble in executing named queries using HibernateTemplate.

Here is my entity class, Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductid", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productid = :productid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductname", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productname = :productname"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductdesc", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productdesc = :productdesc"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByUnitprice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.unitprice = :unitprice"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByStockquantity", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.stockquantity = :stockquantity")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "productid")
private Integer productid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "productname")
private String productname;
@Column(name = "productdesc")
private String productdesc;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "unitprice")
private double unitprice;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "stockquantity")
private int stockquantity;

public Product() {
}

public Product(Integer productid) {
    this.productid = productid;
}

public Product(Integer productid, String productname, double unitprice, int stockquantity) {
    this.productid = productid;
    this.productname = productname;
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
    this.stockquantity = stockquantity;
}

public Integer getProductid() {
    return productid;
}

public void setProductid(Integer productid) {
    this.productid = productid;
}

public String getProductname() {
    return productname;
}

public void setProductname(String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
}

public String getProductdesc() {
    return productdesc;
}

public void setProductdesc(String productdesc) {
    this.productdesc = productdesc;
}

public double getUnitprice() {
    return unitprice;
}

public void setUnitprice(double unitprice) {
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
}

public int getStockquantity() {
    return stockquantity;
}

public void setStockquantity(int stockquantity) {
    this.stockquantity = stockquantity;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (productid != null ? productid.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
        return false;
    }
    Product other = (Product) object;
    if ((this.productid == null && other.productid != null) || (this.productid != null && !this.productid.equals(other.productid))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.pojo.Product[productid=" + productid + "]";
}

}
```

Here is the DAO, ProductDAO.java

```
public class ProductDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport{

public List listProducts() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("Product.findAll");
}
}
```

But when I run the application, I am getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Named query not known: Product.findAll
```

There is already a method- findNamedQuery()- in HibernateTemplate class to run named queries. And the queries are entered as annotations.

Do I need to put that in the mapping file as well?

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to add the Product entity to the *annotatedClasses*?

See here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html